# Why do the singularities of the thermodynamic functions expected to be non-negative powers?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, phase-transition, ising-model

I am going through the first chapter of [Exactly Solved Models in Statistical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486462714). On page 4, at the end of section 1.1 it is said that:

[image]

I would like to know the basis of this expectation. Thanks.

Comment: Can you define these parameters so the reader is not left to infer or chase down references and/or failed links?

Comment: But there is a negative power for the susceptibilities, $\chi$, since $\gamma$ and $\gamma\prime$ are positive.

Comment: @honeste_vivere: These are well-known “critical exponents”; see e.g., the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent).

Comment: @PhilosophiæNaturalis - That was not my point.  It's preferred that parameters be defined within the question or answer so the reader is not left to dig through the internet trying to deconvolve the symbols.  If one makes the question/answer self-contained, it benefits all and is more useful to the community.